# Software to Draw Figures in Algebraic Topology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, soft-question, math-software

I am looking for a software that can allow me to draw oriented graphs with labelled edges, and some other topological figures,very similar to the ones in Allen Hatcher's book https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf pages 58 and 62.

The kinds of software Hatcher used would be very useful to me. I tried some softwares used for knot-plotting, also looked into the packages in LaTeX that could do this directly, yet I could not go far. I am able to draw these figures in Adobe Illustrator, they look fine but then I could not show the orientation and labelling on the figure.

Any kind of help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think Inkscape works for most of the figures. I know papers with surfaces and braids drawn with Inkscape.

Comment: Tikz (LaTeX package) has a steep learning curve, but is fully capable of producing such figures.

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape is great. You can draw some figures, add labels within dollar signs and it will understand you want to use the figure in a latex document.

It will then generate a texfile that you can input. It will convert your labels to proper latex.

Comment: Has anyone tried ipe graphics?